# Using a function as the second argument of a 'for' loop

Tags: c++

Let's assume I have the following code:

```
for(std::vector<int>::iterator i = vect.begin(); i != vect.end(); ++i)
{
    //do smth here
}
```

Is vect.end() going to be re-called each iteration? If yes, how should I iterate a vector then?

Having a function called inside the logical expression (second argument of the for loop) is generally bad practice?

Comment: What are you going to do in the loop? Do you need the index for anything other than dereferencing the correct value?

Comment: The modern form is just `for(int i : vect)`. The compiler knows how to iterate over vectors, lists, arrays and anything that looks similar enough.

Comment: @AlokSave certainly that's not a dupe.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: The answers on the Q address this. esp James Kanze's answer. I don't see merit in someone repeating all of that again here.

Comment: @AlokSave I wasn't certain how this works in terms of performance, the other question has little to do with mine, in my opinion.

Comment: @TedyS.: Read my comment above yours.

Comment: @AlokSave, err no it doesn't, James talks about styles of iterating, not how the bounds should be checked...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it will. However, if the compiler can determine that the value returned by `vect.end()` will never change, it could of course optimize it out. However, if you want to avoid doing it for sure, just change your code to:

```
for(std::vector<int>::iterator i = vect.begin(), end = vect.end();
    i != end; ++i)
{
    //do smth here
}
```

You should, of course, make sure your code doesn't rely on `end()` being checked on every iteration. For example, if you were doing `vect.erase(i)` on elements in your vector, you would need to make sure you got the new `end()` iterator every time (and also make sure you assign the result of `erase` to `i`).

Comment: Or simply `for(std::vector<int>::iterator i = vect.begin(), end=vect.end(); i != end; ++i)`.

Comment: there is a caveat with this approach - if there is a likelyhood that the *do smth here* bit will mutate the vector, your range is now invalid! IMO, it's always safest to use `end()`..

Comment: @us2012 Yes, that's a nicer way to write it - better scoping.

Answer (score 1):

What you have seems perfectly fine. `vect.end()` should be an O(1) operation, so that's not a huge performance hit.

But if your looking for a alternative:

```
typedef std::vector<int>::iterator iter;
iter end = vect.end();
for(iter it = vect.begin(); it != end; ++it) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with that.

or:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator it = vect.begin();
std::vector<int>::iterator end = vect.end();

for(it; it != end; it++) ...
```

or, if your compiler supports C++11 range-based for loops you can iterate the vector like this:

```
for(auto x : vect)
{
    //x is the actual int, not an iterator.
}
```